# Pendulum Confusion

Tags: measurements, kinematics, oscillators

This text in my book is pretty confusing:<sub>With my emphasis</sub>

> A simple pendulum is a *heavy point mass* (bob) suspended from a rigid support by a *massless and inextensible string*. This is an ideal case because **we cannot have** a *heavy mass having the size of a point* and a *string which has no mass*.

At first they say that the string is massless, and bob a heavy point mass, and call it an ideal case. And then, they say that they cannot have a heavy point mass, with a massless string in an ideal case. I suppose this is a mistake. Or maybe is it something else ?

Please clarfiy my doubts.

Thank you!

Comment: They mean that in real life you get a smallish, heavy mass on a light and reasonably inextensible string which is only *almost* the same as the idealized model. You are also generally assuming no frictional losses at the pivot when the real cases is very small frictional losses. This is entirely similar to learning projectile motion in a vacuum to get used to the math.

Comment: @dmckee So it means that in real life we can't have a massless thread or a heavy point mass, and that's what they mean by *we cannot* ? But then, they said the same thing twice in those 2 parts (before/after *we cannot*). Shouldn't the former part be reworded to something else ?

Comment: Don't neglect the words "This is an ideal case".  The first sentence describes the ideal, the second explains why it is an idealization.  Sounds *almost* ok to me: the word "heavy" is unnecessary (and meaningless without saying heavy compared to *what*).   Also implicit, as pointed out by @dmckee, is the ideal pendulum has no friction nor air drag.  And "rigid" is an idealization, etc, etc.

Comment: @garyp So does "ideal case" mean a theoretically-only-posiible case ?

Comment: Yes, that is what an ideal case means.  In physics we often study ideal cases as a way of learning about real systems because the solutions to ideal systems are typically much more easy to understand and the deviations of the 'real' case from the 'ideal' case are often very small.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about clarifying English text rather than any physics concepts.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealization  "*Idealization is the process by which scientific models **assume facts about the phenomenon being modeled that are strictly false** but make models easier to understand or solve. That is, it is determined whether the phenomenon approximates an "ideal case," then the model is applied to make a prediction based on that ideal case."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose this is a mistake. Or maybe is it something else ?

From the Wikipedia article "[Idealization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idealization)"

> Idealization is the process by which scientific models assume facts
>   about the phenomenon being modeled that are strictly false but make
>   models easier to understand or solve. That is, it is determined
>   whether the phenomenon approximates an "ideal case," then the model is
>   applied to make a prediction based on that ideal case.
>
> If an approximation is accurate, the model will have high predictive
>   accuracy; for example, it is not usually necessary to account for air
>   resistance when determining the acceleration of a falling bowling
>   ball, and doing so would be more complicated. In this case, air
>   resistance is idealized to be zero. Although this is not strictly
>   true, it is a good approximation because its effect is negligible
>   compared to that of gravity.

For example, in Electrical Engineering, we learn *ideal circuit theory* where the circuit elements are clearly non-physical; we have resistors with *only* resistance, capacitors with *only* capacitance, wires with *infinite* conductance, etc.

This may seem odd yet, it turns out, we can accurately *model* physical circuits if, *to the desired precision*, the physical circuit elements can be considered ideal.  If not, we can still model physical circuit elements with *combinations* of ideal circuit elements.

Similarly, if it turns out that modelling the pendulum as ideal gives the correct answer to, say, 3 significant figures in a particular case and that's the desired precision, the ideal approximation is a *good* one.

So, ideal models generally simplify calculation and aid comprehension.  **But**, one most always keep in mind the assumptions of the ideal model and learn to recognize the context when those assumptions are no longer reasonable.

Comment: Looks like this problem arose due to my not knowing what is idealization. Thanks for explaining.